# Excel sheet POI Workbook already contains sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm getting this error  :

> the workbook already contains a sheet of this name

```
private void cleanDataSheets(XSSFWorkbook workbookTemplate) {
    int numberOfQueries = extraction.getQueries().size();
    // DATA[maxIndex][minIndex] --> ex : DATA00, DATA01, ..., DATA10
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;
    String sheetName = DATA_SHEET_NAME + maxIndex + minIndex;

    while (maxIndex < numberOfQueries) {
        Sheet sheet = workbookTemplate.getSheet(sheetName);

        if (sheet == null) {
            maxIndex++;
            minIndex = 0;

        } else {
            workbookTemplate.removeSheetAt(workbookTemplate.getSheetIndex(sheet));

            if (minIndex == 0) {
                if (workbookTemplate.getSheetIndex(sheetName) == -1) {
                    workbookTemplate.createSheet(sheetName);
                }

            }
            minIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

The line `if (workbookTemplate.getSheetIndex(sheetName)== -1)`
is supposed to check if the workbook already contains a sheet of this name but it doesn't work. I still have the error.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Does this happen from the first iteration (you have a `while` loop)? Can you give an example what are the sheet names? Plus, can you explain a little bit your code, it looks like it loops over `maxIndex` variable but this variable is only incremented inside an `if` statement which checks for the `sheet == null`. I dont know what you want to achieve but it looks a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the `String sheetName = ...` inside your `while` loop?

The way you have done it, it always try to remove and recreate the same `sheetName` in every loop.

```
private void cleanDataSheets(XSSFWorkbook workbookTemplate) {
    int numberOfQueries = extraction.getQueries().size();
    // DATA[maxIndex][minIndex] --> ex : DATA00, DATA01, ..., DATA10
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;


    while (maxIndex < numberOfQueries) {
        String sheetName = DATA_SHEET_NAME + maxIndex + minIndex;
        Sheet sheet = workbookTemplate.getSheet(sheetName);

        if (sheet == null) {
            maxIndex++;
            minIndex = 0;

        } else {
            workbookTemplate.removeSheetAt(workbookTemplate.getSheetIndex(sheet));

            if (minIndex == 0) {
                if (workbookTemplate.getSheetIndex(sheetName)== -1){
                    workbookTemplate.createSheet(sheetName);
                }

            }
            minIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```